# Error trying to define type Relation [(a,b)] as an instance of Category class

Tags: haskell, category-abstractions

I'm exploring some possible implementations of R subset of AxB, each with its limits and possibilities. I would also like, when possible, to define them as instances of the Category class or Semigroupoid class.

I have chosen the list of pairs since, with regard to the operation of composing lists, it only places types of the elements of the pair the constraint of being instances of the Eq class.

Now I'm stuck on this compiler error message: "No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘°’"

What's wrong?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module RelationT where

import Data.List
import Control.Category as Cat

data RelationT a b where
  Id :: RelationT a a
  RT :: (Eq a, Eq b) => [(a,b)] -> RelationT a b

instance Category RelationT where
  id = Id
  Id . r = r
  r . Id = r
  r1 . r2 = r1 ° r2 -- error:  No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘°’

(°) :: (Eq a, Eq b, Eq t) => RelationT t b -> RelationT a t -> RelationT a b
RT r1 ° RT r2 = RT $ nub $ go r1 r2
    where
    go [] r =  []
    go r [] =  []
    go xys2 ( ((x1,y1): xys1)) =  go2 x1 y1 xys2 [] ++ go xys2  xys1
        where
        go2 x y [] acc = acc
        go2 x y ((w,z):wzs) acc
          | y == w = go2 x y wzs ((x,z):acc)
          | otherwise = go2 x y wzs acc

-- ex. RT [(1,'a'),(4,'b'),(5,'c'),(10,'d')] ° RT [(3,10),(1,5),(1,1)]
-- > RT [(3,'d'),(1,'c'),(1,'a')]
```

Comment: `RT r1 ° RT r2 = RT $ nub [(a, b) | (t, b) <- r1, (a, t') <- r2, t == t']`

Comment: BTW, if you'll want to make this at all useful you'll have to require also `Ord` (or `Hashable`), to avoid the horrible quadratic performance of `nub`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout You are right, but I'm trying also to avoid the Ord constraint. In my previous post I tried Map a (Set b). Sure I'll try a Hashable version.

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani There's nothing especially different about requiring `Eq` or `Hashable` instead of `Ord` -- you have to solve all the same problems. So you might as well use `Map a (Set b)` and use the same solution you've seen here for `Eq`, substituting in `Ord` instead (or `Hashable`, as you prefer).

Comment: @DanielWagner in my previous post, I'd a problem with Map a (Set b) defining a special functor over Set, because Set is not a Functor and is the type in Set are limited to Ord types. Instead, with Map a [b] it was possible to implement that special fmap on [b].

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani Yes, I'm well aware. And you are not going to fix that by requiring `Eq` or `Hashable` instead of `Ord`. You are going to fix it, as in the answer here, by using a different constrained `Functor` class. (And you don't want to drop the `Eq` constraint, or you run the risk of having duplicates in your `Map a [b]`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're storing the `Eq` constraints in a GADT, there's no need to require that from the signature: by pattern-matching on the relation-values, the constraint will already be in scope. So, just change the signature to

```
(°) :: RelationT t b -> RelationT a t -> RelationT a b
```

The `(Eq a, Eq b, Eq c)` information will *still* be available within the function body, because you've pattern-matched `RT r1` and `RT r2` there, which if successful witness that all the types have an `Eq` instance.

That said: in my experience, this trick of storing a constraint in a GADT leads quickly into trouble when you want to do more involved stuff with your category. The problem is, the standard [`Category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html) class is not really suitable for a relation type like this, because it only supports categories which have exactly the same objects as **Hask** – i.e., all Haskell types. But your relation category really has only equality-comparable types as objects; with the extra `Id` constructor you're forcibly extending it to also include relations between non-eq types, but there *only* the identity relation is available... that's quite a fragile hack.

The proper way out is to use a typeclass which allows the categories to have a more restricted notion of objects to begin with. The simplest means to do that are *constraint kinds*. From my [`constrained-categories` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.1.1/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds #-}
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Category k where
  type Object k o :: Constraint
  id :: Object k a => k a a
  (.) :: (Object k a, Object k b, Object k c)
         => k b c -> k a b -> k a c
```

Then you can make the instance

```
data RelationT a b where
  Id :: RelationT a a
  RT :: [(a,b)] -> RelationT a b

instance Category RelationT where
  type Object RelationT o = Eq o
  id = Id
  (.) = (°)
```

Comment: Depending on your goals, it may also be interesting to consider `newtype Relation a b = Relation [(a,b)]; type Object Relation o = (Eq o, Universe o); id = Relation [(x,x) | x <- universe]`. Given that `Universe` is only needed for `id` and `Eq` is only needed for `(.)`, perhaps this is some motivation for `Category` to have a second `Constraint`-kinded associated family (perhaps with a default implementation equal to the first). Something like `type Object k o :: Constraint; type Composes k a b c :: Constraint; type Composes k a b c = (Object k a, Object k b, Object k c)`.